# Gysin sequence for vector-bundle valued cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $M$ be a closed smooth manifold and $E\longrightarrow M$ be a vector bundle with a flat connection 
$$\nabla:\Gamma(E)\longrightarrow \Gamma(T^{*}M\otimes E).$$
Consider the space of differential forms valued in the vector bundle $E$
$$\Omega^{k}(E):=\Gamma(\Lambda^{k}T^{*}M\otimes E).$$
The flat connection $\nabla$ induce a differential 
$$d_{\nabla}：\Omega^{k}(E)\longrightarrow\Omega^{k+1}(E)$$
therefore we can define the cohomology valued in vector bundle
$$H^{*}(M,E)=H^{*}(\Omega^{*}(E),d_{\nabla}).$$
Given a submanifold $N$ of $M$, the restriction of $E$ on $N$ is also a flat vector bundle, hence we have the cohomology $H^{*}(N,E)$. So is there a Gysin sequence of the cohomology valued in the vector bundle $E$ for the pair of $(M,N)$ ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. What you denote $H^*(M,E)$ is actually $H^*(M,E^{\nabla})$, where  $E^{\nabla}$ is the locally constant sheaf of (local) horizontal sections of $E$. And there is a Gysin exact sequence for such sheaves, see for instance Dimca's book *Sheaves in Topology*.